# Can't access directory from netns

Tags: directory, docker, namespace, network-namespaces

I created a simple test netns :

`sudo ip netns add test`

Then I brought up the lo interface.

I'm currently in the home directory of user1, and by executing

`sudo ip netns exec test ls -la`

I see all the files and directories,
however, I can't access a certain directory with

`sudo ip netns exec test cd MyDir`

It just says: " exec of "cd" failed: No such file or directory "

Here are the access rights the directory I cant access:

`drwxr-xr-x  7 user1 user1  4096 Jan 18 20:08 MyDir`

Now it goes without saying that I can access MyDir without any issue from ANYWHERE else NO problem ! It also happens with other directories owned and created by user1.

So why is that, what am I doing wrong? I know anything executed with ip netns exec will be executed as root, but is that the issue?

Comment: It's about the cd command not about ip netns. Try these commands to reproduce your problem *without* involving `ip netns`. Compare `nice sleep 1` versus `nice cd .`.

Answer (score 0):

The cd command was the problem.

Using ls or cat, all is fine.